Vue 3 with TypeScript Referenced project may not disable emit
I'm a newcomer to TypeScript and I've encountered the following issue:
I built a project with Vue 3, Pinia, Vue Router, and Vuetify, but tsconfig file conflicts with references.
This is my configs:
{
  "files": [
    "src/stores/customer.store.ts",
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
}

{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "vite.config.*",
    "vitest.config.*",
    "cypress.config.*",
    "nightwatch.conf.*",
    "playwright.config.*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",

    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}

enter image description here
I have tried thange noEmit from true to false, but it didnt help
"noEmit": false
The project works correctly despite this.
What am I doing wrong?

maybe this related github issue can help.
